# How to iterate over the view items inside a recyclerview?

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` with the following adapter:

```
public class DataTransferMeasureListAdapter extends DataTransferBaseListAdapter<DataTransferMeasureListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context = null;
    private List<DataTransferListEntry> entries = null;

    public DataTransferMeasureListAdapter(Context context, List<DataTransferListEntry> entries) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    @Override
    public DataTransferMeasureListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_datatransfer_measure_list_row, parent, false);

        return new DataTransferMeasureListAdapter.ViewHolder(this.context, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DataTransferMeasureListEntry entry = (DataTransferMeasureListEntry) entries.get(position);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

        String time = Helper.getDateTimePattern(this.context, entry.getDate());
        String value = Helper.getMeasureValue(unit, entry.getValue());

        viewHolder.textViewTime.setText(time);
        viewHolder.textViewValue.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Context context = null;
        private TextView textViewValue = null;
        private TextView textViewTime = null;

        public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.context = context;

            this.textViewValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.datatransfer_measure_list_row_textview_value);
            this.textViewTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.datatransfer_measure_list_row_textview_time);
        }
    }
}
```

In my `ListView`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    this.adapter = new DataTransferMeasureListAdapter(this.getActivity(), this.dataTransferMeasureListEntries);
    this.listRowParent = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.datatransfer_measure_list_row_parent);
    this.listRowParent.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    this.listRowParent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
}
```

I now need a possibility to iterate over each `Viewholder` inside my adapter so that i can change the visibility of some view elements. I need to set it from outside of the adapter.

How can i do that?

Comment: change the data in your model and then call notifyDataSetChanged() / notifyItemChanged(int position) / notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @pskink wrote in the comment.
The fastest and correct way to achieve this is by changing the *entiries* data so that it will contain the values that you will set the visibilty by and then change those from your *fragment* and call *notifyItemChanged* in case one data entry ahs changed or *notifyItemRangeChanged* if a few have changed or *notifyDataSetChanged* if everything changed or a sporadic change has occured.

You dont want the fragment to call methods of the adapter, you want it only to "know" and manipulate the data.